# lateinit property instance has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

When trying to get an instance from the repository in the activity, this error appears and stops the application. If anyone can help, Thank you...

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property instance has not been initialized

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    lateinit var userPreferences: UserPreferencesRepository

    companion object {
        @get:Synchronized
        lateinit var instance: MyApp private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        instance = this


        userPreferences = UserPreferencesRepository.getInstance(this)


    }



}
```

UserPreferencesRepository Class

```
class UserPreferencesRepository (context: Context){

    private val sharedPreferences =
        context.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(APP_SETTINGS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    /**
     * Get the appTheme. By default, theme is set to follow system.
     */
    val appTheme: Theme
        get() {
            val theme = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_NAME_THEME_MODE, Theme.FOLLOW_SYSTEM.name)
            return Theme.valueOf(theme ?: Theme.FOLLOW_SYSTEM.name)
        }

    fun updateTheme(theme: Theme) {
        sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putString(PREF_NAME_THEME_MODE, theme.name)
            .apply()

        ThemeChanger().invoke(theme)
    }


    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserPreferencesRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): UserPreferencesRepository {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE?.let {
                    return it
                }
                val instance = UserPreferencesRepository(context)
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 
I am a beginner and not familiar with android. I just attached the code.

Comment: It's attached now.

Comment: What I mean is post the text instead of a picture of the text. See her: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Tenfour04
I see what you mean, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to set your application class in your manifest, so it’s `onCreate()` is never called.